# VMware Ubuntu boot fails (stuck in initramfs prompt)

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, mount

I've been playing aroung with a Ubuntu Server 10.04 installed through VMware (the host is Windows XP). For any reason (I suspect a power off of my host machine), the guest OS seems broken.

Every time I boot the virtual machine, I get stuck at an initramfs prompt, after what seems like a kernel panic trace and the following lines:

```
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

Busybox seems to allow entering commands, then the (initramfs) prompt is shown.

I booted with a Ubuntu Live CD and tried:

1. Checking entries in `/dev` : I can see `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, `/dev/sda5`
2. Mounting `/dev/sda1`, but the mount command doesn't return (I waited for 10 seconds, I assume that's sufficient?)
3. `fsck -c /dev/sda1` - but fsck reports that `/dev/sda1` is busy.
4. Checking `dmesg` when using the Live CD:

   ```
   EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required in readonly filesystem
   EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
   EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4 clear journal err: Filesystem error recorded from previous mount: IO failure
   EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_clear_journal_err: Marking fs in need of filesystem check.
   ```

What could I try next? The machine contains valuable source code so I'm hoping I can find a solution!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
$ fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

From the LiveCD

Comment: Hi Simon, tried a "last chance" Googling based on "IO failure" message from dmesg output. I found this :https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/668561. So I used Slax to submit the fsck (basically, the Ubuntu Live CD automagically mount /dev/sda1, so it seems not to be possible to fsck it. Maybe with the -y flag, but your answer was too quick, sorry!). Thank you !

Comment: Okay, Hopefully you get things worked out though!

Answer (score 3):

The live CD mounts the /dev/sda1 partition automatically. All you have to do is first run:

```
umount /dev/sda1
```

Then run:

```
fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

That did it for me.